# Alternating DIV and P vertical alignment

Tags: html, css, alignment

I've had this seemingly simple problem nagging me for a good 10 years. (OK, no every day!)

It works fine in IE but doesn't in FF and Chrome, which is usually an indication that something is wrong with the code...
I want to have DIV boxes on both sides (they are actually IMG of various sizes, so don't go on about using a table), with text aligned. Try this example at various window widths. In FF the 3rd line displays ABOVE the preceding DIV. WHY ?

Basically the idea is that the DIVs should stack along each side of the window, with the text in the middle. And if there's too much text, the next div simply gets pushed down. Works fine in IE.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Align test</TITLE>
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
  .DL { float:left;  clear:left;  width:10em; height:10em; background:red;   margin:2; display:inline; }
  .DR { float:right; clear:right; width:10em; height:10em; background:green; margin:2; display:inline; }
  .PL { text-align:left;  background:#F0E0E0;  }
  .PR { text-align:right; background:#E0F0E0;  }
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<DIV CLASS=DL></DIV><P CLASS=PL>This is the 1st line.</P>
<DIV CLASS=DR></DIV><P CLASS=PR>This is the 2nd line.</P>
<DIV CLASS=DL></DIV><P CLASS=PL>This is the 3rd line which should align with the 2nd red square (*)</P>
<DIV CLASS=DR></DIV><P CLASS=PR>This is the 4th line which should align with the 2nd green square.</P>

<P>(*) No, I don't want a clear:right in here. And adding a float:left works fine if the text is short, but moves the right image down if it reaches it, and it moves the whole line down below the left image if it reaches the right border. Which I don't want.</P>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Additional question: if I replace P by SPAN, it's even more messed up. Why is there so much difference between P and SPAN ?

Answer (score 0):

Due to your divs being floated left and right, the `<p>` elements sit in the middle not conforming to anything. They are aligned to neither the left or the right div.

There's actually a fundamental series of flaws in the code in general, so I'll list them all and we can correct them to get the behaviour correct:

1. If you want to keep your left div and p aligned, then think about wrapping them in a parent div container.
2. Think about giving the p element a height to make sure that they stay aligned to each other.
3. Style the parent div with a float of where both elements should be.
4. Don't forget to wrap your HTML attributes in quotes (i.e. `<div class="dl">` - this is more being neat and tidy than anything else).

Anyway, I got to this solution where it's working a bit nicer than before, but it's still not perfect. I'm not sure why you would want a left and right area on the same line rather than alternating the lines between left and right. That layout is not likely to be very aesthetic. Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/z26JM/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Wrapping the DIV/P pairs in DIVs defeats the purpose and cannot be symmetric. In IE, where I originally wrote this over a decade ago, it has a nice style which flows naturally and avoids empty spaces (have you seen it?). I'd like to get it to work in other browsers. How can you give P a height if you don't know if the text will wrap?

Comment: Well I'm not sure I'm understanding what you are trying to end up with. It looks like IE is only working because it's completely bugged. Could you attach an image of how you want the site to look (something quick in paint)?

Comment: Here's the look I'm striving for, straight from IE in quirk mode: http://www.gdargaud.net/BugFest/Align.png (I've replaced the square DIVs with images but the idea is the same).

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the solution: take the clear:left/right out of the DIV/IMG and place it in a P before the DIV. Like this:
    `<P STYLE="clear:left;"></P>`
    `<IMG STYLE="float:left;">`
    `<P STYLE="text-align:left;">...</P>`
Then the other side:
    `<P STYLE="clear:right;"></P>`
    `<IMG STYLE="float:right;">`
    `<P STYLE="text-align:right;">...</P>`
The repeat...